# What is the difference between removeColumn and dropColumn methods on Laravel Framework?

Tags: database, laravel, database-migration

I need to drop a column from a table on a Laravel migration.

The usual code to do it is:

```
$table->dropColumn([ 'city', 'country' ]);
```

But you have to install `Doctrine DBAL` package to use `dropColumn()` method.

Looking for another solution, I have found `removeColumn()` method (http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_removeColumn):

```
$table->removeColumn('city'); 
$table->removeColumn('country');
```

But not seem to work. It does nothing, no fails and leaves intact columns.

What is the difference between removeColumn and dropColumn methods?

Which is the use of removeColumn() method?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The method `removeColumn()` is actually pretty useless for most migrations. It just removes the column from the blueprint and not actually from the database. So if you had this migration:

```
Schema::create('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->string('foo')->nullable();
    $table->string('bar');

    $table->removeColumn('foo');
});
```

The created table would not contain the column `foo` because it is removed from the schema.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why `removeColumn()` method is not for use in migration. And what is the practical application of this method?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. Maybe it could be used in more complicated scenarios where the schema is built dynamically...

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío this question is answered right. Just curious why its not marked as answered?

Comment: No problem, glad you marked it as answered. Apparently I was able to benefit from this answer recently and I though it would increase the chances of the questions being found when its marked.